# When I go to /signin route, it shows me the component of /:username route. How to avoid this?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I understand why is this happening but I can't figure out how to avoid this. The /:username route assumes that the signin parameter in the URL is actually a username, but the thing is that I also have a /signin route.

```
{ path: '/:username', component: Profile, children: [
    { path: '', component: Map , name: 'Profile'},
    { path: 'locations', component: Locations, name: 'Locations'},
    { path: 'map', component: Map, name: 'Map'}
]},
{ path: '/signin', component: Signin, name: 'Signin'}
```

Is there a way to make it so the /:username route assumes the parameter is a username only if there's no other route that uses the same parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Matching Priority](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#matching-priority):

> Sometimes the same URL may be matched by multiple routes. In such a case the matching priority is determined by the order of route definition: the earlier a route is defined, the higher priority it gets.

This means that you have to reorder your router definition.

```
{ path: '/signin', component: Signin, name: 'Signin'},
{ path: '/:username', component: Profile, children: [ /* ... */ ]},
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.